# Why is glass green?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, refraction

When I look at a glass block at an angle the edges appear green, but when I look at the edge sideways, so that is directly in front of my eyes it appears transparent. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Most glass contains iron oxide as an impurity which gives the glass a slightly green hue. When you're looking straight through a pane of glass you don't notice it because the glass is so thin. But when you look down the side it becomes apparent because of the thickness.

Comment: The same happens for a thick glass block too. Why?

Comment: @NazmusSaadat I answered your question in the "duplicate original"....(I don't know how to call it correctly)