# Why is window glass only transparent from one directional axis?

Tags: optics

If you look through a pane of common window glass the way it was meant to be looked through, it's clear.  But if you look at it from the side it's not very clear at all, but a dark green color.

One might think at first that this is due to thickness, that the glass is actually green (but highly translucent) throughout, but when looking straight through a pane it's thin enough that you don't notice the green color.  But if you pick up a small piece of a broken window, a shard no larger than the thickness of a window pane, you can still see that it's transparent from one direction but dark green when looked at from the side, so clearly (no pun intended) it has to do with some property of the glass itself and the angle at which it's looked through, rather than the thickness of the glass.

Can anyone explain why the same uniform material has a radically different color depending on which way the light travels through it on the way to your eyes?

Comment: The green color in the glass comes from iron. You can get (much more expensive) low iron glass that is marketed under a number of different names like UltraWhite. You can see the difference e.g. here: http://www.austinstairs.com/faqs/16-otherreferences/144-comparison-of-regular-glass-and-low-iron-glass.html

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why is glass green?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/247939/)

Comment: The answer to the question in the last sentence - it travels different path lengths in the different directions. If you cut up the glass and polished the side surfaces, it would look just the same.

Comment: An earlier possible duplicate : Viewing glass from an oblique angle, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105693

Comment: I don't think your observation is correct.  I have tried it.  Small shards of glass which are about as wide as the thickness between parallel faces, are transparent, not dark green... A large pane is dark green at the edge because most of the light emerging there has travelled the whole width of the pane, due to total internal reflection.  If you stack panes to the same thickness as the width, you will see the same amount of green.